# What's the word for having the same distance to neighbours?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine I have dots on a line and the dots have all the same distance to their neighbours. What is the word for that? I am searching for a word which comes from Latin for a scientific text. I think the word starts with "homo-" and I'd guess it is "homo-distant" or something similar, but I am not quite sure. I also need the opposite, as in non-WORD (maybe hetero-distant?). An alternative might be "homogeneous", but that would be a bit too general. Another alternative might be "monotonous", but that is also rather general.

Example sentences:

> Qualitative features can be discrete and WORD or discrete and non-WORD, or continuous.
>
> The data-points are WORD.

Comment: Haha, it's like waiting for a bus, isn't it? At least you can be sure equidistant is a good answer! XD

Comment: As an aside, the prefixes "homo" and "equi" are similar in meaning: "homo-" is from greek while "equi-" is from latin.  So "homodistant" is a good guess.

Comment: The opposite is *non-equidistant*. Here's [an example](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02946) of its use.

Comment: @JohnClifford: What do you mean by "it's like waiting for a bus"?

Comment: You were waiting for an answer and four came along at once.

Comment: To be pedantic, if all are on a line, then the points are not all equidistant, just the adjacent points are equidistant. I think a relevant word is then 'equally spaced' or 'regularly spaced' (and use 'not' for the opposite.

Comment: Has anyone mentioned 'equidistant' yet? :)

Comment: @MarvMills I don't believe so! Why has nobody thought of that?

Comment: Regular, irregular; Centered, biased; equidistant, inequidistant; even, uneven spacing

Comment: Consistent or fixed vs. Inconsistent, varied or variable distance, too.

Comment: "Uniform" and "uniformly distributed" come to mind.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You probably mean [equidistant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equidistant):

> - Equally distant.

[Equidistant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=equidistant):

> - 1560s, from French équidistant (14c.), ***from Late Latin aequidistantem (nominative aequidistans), from aequi- (see equal (adj.)) + distans (see distant)***. In reference to a type of map projection, from 1866.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Sorry Josh, I didn't notice your answer until I'd posted mine; would you like me to delete it since you were first?

Comment: I think we all had the same idea at the same moment...nobody copied.

Comment: True, but your answer is more detailed than mine and the question doesn't really need four identical answers. XD

Comment: @JohnClifford just vote it up then.

Comment: @MaxWilliams That...would make far too much sense.

Comment: So, do I say "non-equidistant"?

Comment: @Make42 See Andrew Leach's answer: there isn't really an opposite to equidistant because that's the "default": that said, there are occurrences online of "non-equidistant" (49,400 results on Google) so it's clearly used by some people.

Comment: @Make42 - I think you can: http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02946#

Comment: I'm not happy with 'equidistant' being implied to be an exact synonym of 'equally spaced'. I'd require 'the points are equidistant _from their neighbours_ at the very least (and would choose 'equally spaced' anyway). There _are_ examples of 'equidistant' used without 'from' on the internet, but I haven't found a dictionary giving say 'equidistant points along a line' as an example.

Comment: @Edwin: In the case of 'equidistant points along a line', other phrases are *regular intervals* (and the obvious opposite, *irregular intervals*).  *periodic* (opposite: *aperiodic*) is also applicable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why wouldn't _equidistant_ be an exact synonym of _equally spaced_ ? You don't need the _from_, its absence is what makes "from their neighbours" implicit.

Comment: @SantiBailors As the word is at least most often used, points (B, C, D etc) are all equidistant from a given point (A say), not pairwise.

Answer (score 14):

The word you want is ***equidistant.***

> At equal distances:
>   *the line joins together all points which are equidistant from the two axes*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equidistant)]

There isn't a word which means not equidistant, because that's the usual case. Being equidistant is the special case which is unusual. You'd need to say something like "all at different distances".

Comment: The word I know that is the opposite of 'equidistant' is 'varidistant'. I can't find it in any dictionaries, but I do get some results from academic papers when I google it (use the verbatim option).

Comment: I didn't even know this was a word, but was the first thing to pop into my head when I read the title.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you want dots which are [***equidistant***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equidistant).

> of equal distance : located at the same distance (*a location **equidistant** from two major cities*)
>
> *Merriam-Webster*

As for an opposite, although not an "official" antonym, "non-equidistant" is probably the most appropriate one. It's definitely used by some people, having 49,400 Google results at the time of searching (some of which appear to be quite prolific research papers)

Comment: haha, when i started typing there were no answers.  Stupid mininum 30 char limit :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see Josh's until I posted mine. I feel I should delete this one since he answered first.

Comment: LOL, now there's four of them. Keep them all, it makes the answer(s) all the more decisive.

Comment: I'd say that all of these answers are *equidistant* from perfection. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I know you've already accepted an answer but I thought it would be nice to not provide a fifth equidistant answer so my proposal is the word **pitch**.

From my experience, I have most commonly associated it to pixel pitch in monitors measured in µm

> All of these dots have the same **pitch**

I know it's not a one-word answer due to the use of "same" but it does provide variety.

Answer (score 3):

For a pair, **regularly/irregularly spaced**.

> Regularly:  3 with an even shape, or arranged with an equal amount of
>   space between objects The city planted trees along the streets at
>   regularly spaced intervals.

MacMillan: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/regularly

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to the list the word **[equispaced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equispaced).** This is what I would personally choose.

To comment on the other answers:

- *same pitch*, *uniform distribution*, *equally/evenly spaced* are all correct answers in my opinion;
- I think *equidistant* is not ideal: I would rather use it to say that A, B and C have the same distance to a common point Z, not to each other.

Answer (score 1):

*Equidistant* is probably the best answer, but if you want to keep it to well known words, you might consider *uniformly spaced* or *uniformly distributed*.

Answer (score 0):

Homologous is probably the word with the 'homo-' prefix you were looking for.

[homologous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/homologous)
[huh-mol-uh-guh s, hoh-]

adjective
1. having the same or a similar relation; corresponding, as in relative position or structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally choose *equidistant*, as other answers have already mentioned, but if you are still looking for alternatives, in mathematics two common terms are:

### homogeneous

As in:

> The distribution of dots is homogeneous
>
> The data points are distributed homogeneously

or, probably slightly better

### uniform

As in:

> The datapoints are uniformly distributed over the interval *[X, Y]*

or, within proper context:

> The distribution of the dots can be uniform, non-uniform or continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***[evenly](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evenly) distant*** and ***equally distant***

> *Suzette felt the cold water around her thighs. A shiver chased away the sun's warmth. They were in the middle of the passage now, about evenly distant from the mainland and the island.*
>
> [Trouble at Fort La Pointe](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZGbZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&dq=%22evenly-distant%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5sPP6joDMAhWBvxoKHVLXDMk4FBDoAQg7MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22evenly-distant%22&f=false)
>
> *Equal straight lines in a circle are equally distant from the center, and those which are equally distant from the center equal one another.*
>
> [aleph0.clarku.edu](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII14.html)

Also, ***halfway***

> : in the middle between two points.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halfway)